# What is a efficient way to delete the most recent X record from SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a simple table where one of the field is a date column. I can select the most recent X records by doing

```
Select * from MyTable order by last_update desc limit X
```

But how do I efficiently delete those column? Is subselect the quickest?

Comment: How many records are you talking about deleting at a time 1, 100, 1000, 1000000 ?

Comment: Isn't it a little rash just deleting the last 10? Isn't there a specific 10 that you had in mind? If you know the IDs then use those in an IN clause.

Comment: No, I want specifically the last 10

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly the IN clause accepts a sub select. Could be wrong.

```
DELETE FROM Person 
WHERE 
  Person.ID IN ( 
     SELECT t.ID 
     FROM 
        Person t 
     ORDER BY 
        t.joinTime DESC
     LIMIT X
   )
```

Comment: if you want the newest should it be ORDER BY t.joinTime DESC?

Comment: IN is very inefficient. You should always do a JOIN instead of IN ( subselect)

Comment: How would you do it with a join instead?

Comment: This won't work in `MySQL`, `IN (SELECT ... LIMIT)` is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

You can do "delete from where" in exactly the same way, with the same conditions as the original query.
e.g:

```
DELETE FROM Person WHERE Person.name = "jeff"
```

or

```
DELETE FROM Person WHERE Person.joinTime > 12001234567 LIMIT 100
```

If you want to delete a range (e.g most recent 10) you could try:

```
DELETE * FROM Person WHERE id >= ( LAST_INSERT_ID() - 10 );
```

Comment: The `12001234567` could also be replaced with a select subquery that finds the timestamp for the cutoff record.

Comment: My table does not have an id field, only dates. None of your queries does what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE rowid IN
(SELECT rowid FROM MyTable ORDER BY last_update DESC LIMIT X);
```

Comment: should this be "IN" instead of "="

Comment: This won't work in `MySQL`, `IN (SELECT ... LIMIT)` is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE  d.*
FROM    mytable d
LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    mytable
        ORDER BY
                last_update DESC
        LIMIT   10
        ) q
ON      d.id = q.id
WHERE   q.id IS NULL
```

If your are using `MySQL`, this is the preferred solution, since `IN (SELECT ... LIMIT)` does not work in `MySQL`.

See this entry in my blog for more details:

- [**Keeping rows**](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/07/keeping-rows/)